# Spring Boot Microservices with Firebase JPA REST or Admin SDK

Tags: java, spring, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-realtime-database

We have a React application uses Firebase as the backend.  I need to build a set of microservices to integrate some additional functionality.  I'm using Spring Boot because my background is heavy Java/Spring/Spring Boot/JPA and I'm using some Apache Java libs to help build out the functionality.  I'm really struggling with how to integrate with Firebase.

Here's where I have focused so far:

1. I'm most comfortable (aka lazy) with Spring Boot using JPA to integrate with Mongo/MySQL/etc.  I haven't been able to locate a JPA solution for Firebase and I don't have the time to write anything custom at the moment.
2. There are several Firebase SDKs in Maven repos.  Google recently announced that Firebase integration should use the new Admin SDK.  This is a viable solution and is under consideration.
3. In doing my research, I came across Square's Retrofit lib.  It will allow me to integrate with the Firebase REST API fairly easily.

Most of the Java focused Firebase documentation is centered around Android development and not server development. Hopefully that will change with Google's recent increase in attention to Firebase.

Are any of these a viable approach?

**UPDATE**

Sometimes writing the issue out helps to find the errors of your ways...

I was getting too tied up in the JPA mode.  I found a Firebase Android sample application on Github.  The Android SDK is very similar to the service Admin SDK.  Going through the code I was able to get a good start on CRUD with Firebase.

So, now my question is more about scalability and best practice.

Comment: Hi spdaly, I am in the same position, did you learn anything you would like to share?

Comment: I found a library called firebomb https://github.com/akhahaha/firebomb-java. It's making it a lot easier.